# Solve the recurrence: $T(n)= 4T(\frac{n}{2} )+\frac{n^2}{\log n}$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I have been trying to solve the sequence

> $T(n)= 4T(\frac{n}{2} )+\frac{n^2}{\log n},$
>
> $T(1)=1$

after calculations, I came to this

> $4^k Τ(\frac{n}{2^k})+ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{n^2}{log\frac{n}{2^i}}$

The only thing I can imagine is the $4^k T(\frac{n}{2^k}) + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{n^2}{log\frac{n}{2^i}}$  behaves the same as the harmonic series and therefore can be approximated as $\log(k)$, but I cant find a proof for that.

Because when I set $\log n=k,$ I end up with: $n^2 \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-i}$ for which I can't find a "proof" for the relation between this and the harmonic series, since the harmonic series has a form of $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{1}{i}$, and not $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-i}$.

Any suggestions on how I can solve the problem will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 2b of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) immediately gives $T(n)=\Theta(n^2\log\log n)$.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean, but does this make so that I can't use the the recurrences method to calculate the time complexity?

Comment: @EK208 You could do what you did, and you would notice that the summation gives a harmonic series with a $\log n$ upper bound on the denominators, which explains the $\log\log n$.

Comment: You are right, by setting logn=k I end up with: n^2 sum from i to k-1 1/(k-i). But I can't find a "proof" for the reletion between this and the harmonic series, since the harmonic series has a form of sum from i=0 to k (1/i) and not 1/(k-i).